# Keras/Tenserflow - Cannot make model.fit() work

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to make a CNN network to make predictions on images of mushrooms.

Sadly, I can't even begin to train my model, the fit() method always gives me errors.

There are 10 classes, the tf Datasets correctly found their names based on their subfolders.

With my current code, it says:

```
InvalidArgumentError:  logits and labels must have the same first
dimension, got logits shape [12800,10] and labels shape [32]
```

Model summary:

```
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================  
input_5 (InputLayer)        [(None, 64, 64, 3)]       0         
                                                                           
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)           (None, 62, 62, 32)        896       
                                                                           
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling  (None, 20, 20, 32)       0              
2D) 
    
                                                                       
re_lu_2 (ReLU)              (None, 20, 20, 32)        0         
                                                                       
dense_2 (Dense)             (None, 20, 20, 10)        330 

  
                                                                 
=================================================================
```

Here's my code:

```
#Data loading
train_set = keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
      data_path, 
      labels="inferred",
      label_mode="int",
      batch_size=32, 
      image_size=(64, 64),
      shuffle=True,
      seed=1446,
      validation_split = 0.2,
      subset="training")

validation_set = keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_path, 
  labels="inferred",
  label_mode="int",
  batch_size=32, 
  image_size=(64, 64),
  shuffle=True,
  seed=1446,
  validation_split = 0.2,
  subset="validation")

#Constructing layers
input_layer = keras.Input(shape=(64, 64, 3))
x = layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu")(input_layer)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3))(x)
x = keras.layers.ReLU()(x)
output = layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")(x)

#Making and fitting the model
model = keras.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output)
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_set, epochs=5, validation_data=validation_set)
```

Comment: Welcome. Please tell us what exactly your error is. Also, don't use `input` as variable name since `input` is a built-in function.

Comment: I corrected the name for the input variable. With the current code, it spits out: "logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [12800,10] and labels shape [32]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to flatten before passing to the `Dense` layer

```
input_layer = keras.Input(shape=(64, 64, 3))
x = layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu")(input_layer)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3))(x)
x = keras.layers.ReLU()(x)
x = keras.layers.Flatten()(x) # try adding this
output = layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")(x)
```

Comment: This worked, thanks a ton! I I'm gonna look it up to  try to understand why. At least I can actually start working now :)

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is to add a flatten layer in your model between the ReLU layer and the output layer.

```
input_layer = keras.Input(shape=(64, 64, 3))
x = layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation="relu")(input_layer)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3))(x)
x = keras.layers.ReLU()(x)
x = keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
output = layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")(x)
```

When you see model.fit throw an error due to the difference in logits and labels it is a good idea to print out the model summary

```
print(model.summary())
```

By looking at the summary it usually helps figure out what is wrong.

Comment: This worked, and great advice, I'll update my post with the summary in case anybody encounters the same problem as me.